# Indexing dynamic loading page

Tags: google, search-engine-indexing, ajax

Does Google index dynamic loading page?

**For example**

*index.html*

```
<div id="dynamic_message"></div>
```

*index.html after few seconds*

```
<div id="dynamic_message">Hello Google, do you see me?</div>
```

Will Google index div#dynamic_message? Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean the page content is created with JavaScript/Ajax?

Comment: @John Yes, yes, yes.

Answer (score 2):

Google can index dynamic content if you [follow their proposal for allowing such content to be indexed](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/10/proposal-for-making-ajax-crawlable.html).

Comment: Beyond experimental proposals such as this, though, a search engine will not be able to index content injected into the DOM after page load. Since web crawlers cannot typically execute JS, the logic to insert the additional information never gets executed.